Import pandas not working, showing "RESTART: shell"
whenever im using import pandas as pd it isn't working other than that anything like import math module is working.
it shows "RESTART: shell".
i am unable to install any other IDE so i am working on python IDLE. even VS code is giving error.
Please help me. I've tried re-installing python or pandas.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If in IDLE you see something like
>>> import pandas

================================ RESTART: Shell ================================
>>> 

and no traceback such as
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

or one with another error, then almost certainly something called pandas or pandas.py was found on sys.path and execution was attempted with the result that the python subprocess doing the execution crashed.  Perhaps you have a file called pandas.py in your current directory, or perhaps the installed pandas file has a messed-up byte.
